# SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character в программе "Hello World"

Tags: python

Только сегодня поставил Питон и приступил к изучению. Написал в IDLE:

```
>>>print("hello world")
```

IDLE вернул, все супер. Сохранил в hw.py, интерпретатор не запускает файл и ругается вот так вот

> "SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character"

Что он хочет от меня?

Comment: win10, python 3.7 на другой машине та же самая петрушка.

Comment: ошибка в синтаксисе - копию содержимого файла добавьте

Comment: print("hello world")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем файле `hw.py` у вас где-то в строке символ `\` и за ним ещё что-то - вы его не видите, потому он где-то за правым краем окна.

Проходите каждую строку а на каждой из ней нажмите на клавиатуре клавишу <kbd>End</kbd>.

Потом излишние символы удалите, файл сохраните и снова напишите

```
python hw.py
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за совет. Я уже дома и на домашнем ПК пытаюсь провернуть тоже самое. В коде одна строчка. Никаких символов быть не может. (это третья за сегодня машина, на которую я поставил Питон). Вообще я до этого только с JS дело имел. Может я что-то не так делаю - сейчас уже просто набрал код в Атоме и сохранил с расширением .py - Не представляю в чем тут дело. И не стоит забывать что консоль отлично возвращает результат. Может дело в пути к файлу, там же тоже фигурируют слеши?

Comment: Пути к файлу записываются в зависимости от операционной системы (Windows, Linux, ...), лучше всего с `/` и в кавычках, когда в них пробели. У меня всё бес проблем, с путей или без пути. Возможно, что у вас 2 файлы `hw.py` (в разных папках) и вы редактируете один, но запускаете другой? Попробуйте написать вашу программу прямо в IDLE (как новый файл) и потом запускать её клавишем `F5` - IDLE будет хотеть сохранить вашу программу в файле, напишите имя для него и потом попробуйте работать с этим файлом.

Answer (score 0):

Кодировку стоит проверить, должна быть utf-8, у меня такое былоЮ если файл в cp1251 сохранен